# Generating Inheritance classes using "x-ms-discriminator-value" value

Tags: c#, nswag

I am currently using NSwag to generate a API Client using the following in the csproj file.

```
 <ItemGroup>
   <OpenApiReference Include="OpenAPIs\FormRecognizer.json" CodeGenerator="NSwagCSharp" Options="/OperationGenerationMode:SingleClientFromOperationId /ClientClassAccessModifier:internal /GenerateClientInterfaces:true">
     <SourceUri>https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/azure-rest-api-specs/main/specification/cognitiveservices/data-plane/FormRecognizer/stable/2023-07-31/FormRecognizer.json</SourceUri>
   </OpenApiReference>
 </ItemGroup>
```

This generates code like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Get Operation response object.
/// </summary>
[Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter(typeof(JsonInheritanceConverter), "kind")]
[JsonInheritanceAttribute("DocumentModelBuildOperationDetails", typeof(DocumentModelBuildOperationDetails))]
[JsonInheritanceAttribute("DocumentModelComposeOperationDetails", typeof(DocumentModelComposeOperationDetails))]
[JsonInheritanceAttribute("DocumentModelCopyToOperationDetails", typeof(DocumentModelCopyToOperationDetails))]
[JsonInheritanceAttribute("DocumentClassifierBuildOperationDetails", typeof(DocumentClassifierBuildOperationDetails))]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("NJsonSchema", "13.20.0.0 (NJsonSchema v10.9.0.0 (Newtonsoft.Json v13.0.0.0))")]
public partial class OperationDetails
{
```

However the Azure endpoint send back the "kind" value being the swagger.json file and not the class name

```
"DocumentModelBuildOperationDetails": {
  "description": "Get Operation response object.",
  "x-ms-discriminator-value": "documentModelBuild",
  "type": "object",
  "allOf": [
    {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/OperationDetails"
    }
  ],
```

Is there a way to get NSWAG Toolchain to create the JsonInheritanceAttribute statement using the value from the "x-ms-discriminator-value" value pair?  So that the code is generated as this?

```
/// <summary>
/// Get Operation response object.
/// </summary>
[Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter(typeof(JsonInheritanceConverter), "kind")]
[JsonInheritanceAttribute("documentModelBuild", typeof(DocumentModelBuildOperationDetails))]
[JsonInheritanceAttribute("documentModelCompose", typeof(DocumentModelComposeOperationDetails))]
[JsonInheritanceAttribute("documentModelCopyTo", typeof(DocumentModelCopyToOperationDetails))]
[JsonInheritanceAttribute("documentClassifierBuild", typeof(DocumentClassifierBuildOperationDetails))]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("NJsonSchema", "13.20.0.0 (NJsonSchema v10.9.0.0 (Newtonsoft.Json v13.0.0.0))")]
public partial class OperationDetails
{
```

TIA